# PHP- obter os ultimos 4 id's inseridos na base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho uma base de dados em que uma das tabelas tem a designação de "Products" e gostaria de extrair dela os últimos 4 itens inseridos nela. A coluna com a chave principal (primary key) é autoincriment.

Ao fazer a query Sql, ao usar "Limit 4" é o bastante para ir buscar as últimas 4, ou não? Ou será que torno o processo mais fácil se criar dentro da tabela uma coluna do tipo datetime, em que sempre que é inserido um novo item este guarda a data e hora em que foi inserido?

P.S: Estou a usar base de dados MySql

Comment: Você deseja saber quais os últimos 4 registros gravados por qualquer usuário do sistema, ou você quer saber quais os últimos 4 registros inseridos em um único INSERT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o código que você esteja buscando seja:

```
SELECT id FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Além do `LIMIT 4` você precisa ordenar por ordem decrescente, para que busque os 4 últimos e não os 4 primeiros.

O coluna com a data em que foi adicionada pode ser útil, mas não sei se seria tão útil se seu único uso for para ordenar, visto que você já possui uma chave primária, mas poderia ser usada para outros fins.

Vale lembrar que o atributo `LIMIT 4` deve ser usado *após* o `ORDER BY`, caso contrário, ele irá limitar a 4 registros (seja eles os primeiros ou os últimos) antes de ordenar os registros. Portanto, use o `LIMIT 4` ao final da *query*.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! esqueci-me completamente do order by!!!

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente uso:

```
 order by tabela.id_da_tabela desc limit 4
```